# C# Invoked method by reflection cant access data from public static members

Tags: c#, static, invoke

I got three classes. First one `public static class DataContainer`, second `public class DoInvocations` and third `public class Execute`. *(note: these are just example names for easier understanding)* The class `DoInvocations` gets certain assembly information from the `DataContainer` about the class `Execute`. In order to be able to invoke a method from this class.

So after i got the assembly information the requested method is invoked successful in the class `DoInvocations`.

```
invokeInformation.InvokeMember(
                DataContainer.MethodName,
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, null, inputParamList);
```

`MethodName` is a `public static string prop{ get; private set; }` from `DataContainer`, so it should be accessible for all other classes.

---

Now in the `Execute` class the invoked method doesnt have any access to the `public static` members of the `DataContainer` class. If i want to access them all their values are `null`.

```
public class Execute
{
    public static void DoSomething() //DoSomething is the earlier DataContainer.MethodName
    {
        string whatEver = DataContainer.MethodName;
    }
}
```

`whatEver` turns out to be `null`. When i invoke the method right after that again (without reloading any information to the `DataContainer`) the invoke is successful again. So the information wasnt gone or whatever. It seems like after the invoke method the class `Execute` accesses an empty instance of the `DataContainer`, but because the class is `static` it´s already impossible to create an instance of it. I really dont know what is going on in my code.

I alreay set a breakpoint the the `MethodName` prop, but it never got changed. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Agreed. Will reconsider my question and ask it again. **But** if you want actual working code my post will get a bit longer. just with the most little required code though. I´ll try that though, because i can really relate that this longer post, referring to the text, discourages everybody.

Comment: Some multi-threading kicking in setting the value of `DataContainer.MethodName` to domething different? From what you´ve posted itßs impossible to guess why the property is null.

Comment: No, i didnt use any multi threading here.

Comment: My crystal ball says that there are *two* DataContainer classes.  In different assemblies.  In other words, you incorrectly used the same source file more than once in different projects.  Instead of having one project reference another so there is only one.

Comment: @HansPassant But i didnt define any other class named `DataContainer` in an other assembly. And i didnt set any reference to another project, so i cant even access other assemblies from this class.

Comment: @mjwills No unfortenately not, i couldnt find any mistake or something that coud eventually cause the problem. I wrote a similar test program with the same references and the same invoke, but the problem does not appear there. The only difference between them is now, that the most basic execution of the programm is in another assembly. So let´s say my `main()` method is in assembly1 and the `main()` method calls instantly on execution the `Run()` method from a class in assembly2. `Run` only calls classes and methods from assembly2 and but i set the right assembly for the invocation.

Comment: I´ll try that out if this somehow causes the problem, but since i get the correct assembly for the invocation (otherwise compiler would beef) i dont understand why this would cause a problem. Shell i update you with the information i´ll gather?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I loaded the *wrong* assembly. Because I loaded the assembly directly from the file path:

```
Assembly TestAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("...\\somePath.dll");
```

The problem is that this assembly didn't get initialised, that's why the property `DataContainer.MethodName` always returned the value `null`.

So I simply loaded the assembly of the desried `.dll` this way, to get the *current* initialised assembly.

```
Assembly TestAssembly = typeof(DataContainer).Assembly;
```

Since the property `DataContainer.MethodName` was initialised then, and I didn't load the plain uninitialised `.dll`, it returned the expected value instead of `null` and the invocation was successful.

```
Type invokeInformation = TestAssembly.GetType(...);

invokeInformation.InvokeMember(
            DataContainer.MethodName,
            ...);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you *said* you were doing. It works just as one would expect it to work. So you will need to figure out what *else* you do, that makes your application fail.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    using System;
    using System.Reflection;

    public static class DataContainer
    {
        public static string MethodName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DoInvocations
    {
        public void Method()
        {
            typeof(Execute).InvokeMember(
                DataContainer.MethodName,
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
                null, null, null);
        }
    }

    public class Execute
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DataContainer.MethodName);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DataContainer.MethodName = "DoSomething";

            new DoInvocations().Method();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Some things other people did wrong when they had the same problems: some people expect `static` to mean globally, no matter where the DLL is loaded. That's not the case. Each time the library is loaded, it get's it's own memory. So make sure everything you do is inside the same process.

Generally speaking, having static properties is *not* a good way to communicate between instances even in the same process. That's what method arguments are for. Maybe you can find a way to actually pass your method name along to the methods that need it, that will most likely make your problem disappear anyway.

Comment: Thanks for dealing with shortening my question. (+1 for effort) I know that this is not the best approach, but since it is quite difficult to pass this instance along the methods i considered defining the class as `static` and accessing the members this way would be way easier.